# need the cound of Row C if the condition of Row A and B is match

Tags: excel

IN row A i am having Date (Date might be today's date, yesterday’s date and day before yesterday's date)
In Row B i am having person name (Name Can be Arindam , Samir,Amit,Din
In Row C I am having the work status (Ctatus Can be Closed,Work in progress,Waiting,New

Now I want the Close Count status of Row C in Row D, but condition should be” if Row A is today's date and Row C is Arindam.”
Is it possible by excel formula?
Please help me out

Comment: [Again!?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21509223/1578604) Can't you just adjust the formula you were given?

Comment: no Jerry actually I am very much new in excel world can you please help me out...plzzzzzzz

Comment: Hi Jerry I need something like this =COUNTIFS(A1:A10=TODAY(),B1:B10="Arindam",C1:C10,"New").....BY which i can get the count of NEW which is in C1:C10 –

Comment: You don't use `=` in `COUNTIFS`. You simply use `,`: `=COUNTIFS(A1:A10,TODAY(),B1:B10,"Arindam",C1:C10,"New")`

Comment: Thanks a lot Jerry its Done

Comment: Hi @Jerry can u tell me how to put the "not=" formula in this...example =COUNTIFS(A1:A10,TODAY(),B1:B10,"Arindam",C1:C10,"not=New")how should i apply this ?

Comment: You can use 'not equal to' (`<>`) in this case: .......... `=COUNTIFS(A1:A10,TODAY(),B1:B10,"Arindam",C1:C10,"<>New")`

Comment: hi @Jerry thanks a lot, now i stuck in other problem.suppose in A1:A10 some dates are there and in B1:B10 i am having some receipt number .I want to count all the  Receipt number which is of today's date in A1:A10...I have tried =COUNTIFS(B1:B10,A1:A10,TODAY()) but it is not working...can you help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, but there are a LOT better ways to organize your data (like with Tables and named Columns) that will make this kind of thing easier.

```
=IF(AND(A1=TODAY(), B1="Arindam"), C1, "")
```

You can "fill" that formula down the whole column D and the row number will auto-adjust.  You might need to edit the A1/B1/C1 to match the row you actually paste this into (probably row 2 or greater, if you have a header row).

Op asked a follow-up that couldn't be easily answered in a comment.

From Excel help:

> The COUNTIF function counts the number of cells within a range that
>   meet a single criterion that you specify.

COUNTIFS is a more complex variation of that.

For the original example given, the simple IF() above works correctly.  COUNTIF is meant to count the NUMBER of cells (not to sum them) that meet certain criteria (like Date>Today, Count>3, or anything).  There is a SUMIF that will sum up cells, but you didn't say you want to sum up cells, you said wanted the "Close Count status of Row C in Row D".

If instead you want a cell (not necessarily in column D, associated with the data in a single row) that "sums" up all of a given Close Count on a page, you could do this:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"="& TODAY(),B:B,"Arindam")
```

That's really great for a summary of ALL the rows of data, but it sounded like you wanted a summary per row, for which you should use the simpler IF() given above.

OK, one more update, now that I'm understand the original data better.  This can be done in EACH row, and if you really want a total for the entire set of data, you'll have to have a total row (or separate sheet) that adds up column D:

```
=IF(AND(A1=TODAY(), B1="Arindam", C1="Closed"), 1, "")
```

This puts a "1" in column D if the criteria in columns A, B, and C match what you want.

If you want a single cell that sums up all the matches, then Jerry gave the correct answer (this is from him, and I think it's the best answer, although it was in the comments):

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A10,TODAY(),B1:B10,"Arindam",C1:C10,"New")
```

Comment: Sir I am not having the count of C in this formula ..can you please help me out.

Comment: What row number did you paste this into?  If it wasn't row  #1, you need to edit the "1" in the A1/B1/C1 text in the formula to use the row number (like A2/B2/C2 if it's row #2, etc.).

Comment: I need somthing like this =COUNTIFS(A1:A10=TODAY(),B1:B10="Arindam",C1:C10,"New").....BY which i can get the count of NEW which is in C1:C10

Comment: Row A(Date)        Row B (NAME)     Row C
04/02/2014        Arindam            New
03/02/2014        Samir              New
04/02/2014        Arindam            New
04/02/2014        Arindam            Working
04/02/2014        Samir              New
03/02/2014        Arindam            New
04/02/2014        Samir              Working
04/02/2014        Arindam            Working
04/02/2014        Samir              New
03/02/2014        Arindam            New

Now i want the NEW count of Arindam of 04/02/2014